# How to compute $\int_c \frac{ \cos(z)}{ z^2 (z-1)}$ on the circle |z|=3/2 without the residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

How does one integrate

$\int_C \frac{ \cos(z)}{z^2 (z-1)}$  on the circle C: |z|=3/2?

We cannot use partial fractions and the function is not analytic at z=0 and z=1 which are both in C.

Thanks

Comment: So, you may not use the residue theorem and you may not use partial fraction expansion.  Are you allowed to deform the contour using Cauchy's Integral Theorem?

Comment: None of the poles are in C (on C). They are within the domain enclosed by C, which is way another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By cauchy integral formula We know that $$f^n(a) =\frac{n!}{2i\pi}\int_c\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}$$
and

$$\frac{\cos z}{z^2(z-1)} =\frac{\cos z}{z-1}-\frac{\cos z}{z}-\frac{\cos z}{z^2}$$ then applies Cauchy integral formula, 
to get 
$$\int_c \frac{ \cos(z)}{ z^2 (z-1)}=\int_c \frac{\cos z}{z-1}-\int_c\frac{\cos z}{z}-\int_c\frac{\cos z}{z^2} = \color{red}{2i\pi(\cos 1- \cos 0 - (\cos z)'|_{z=0})}\\ = \color{red}{2i\pi(\cos 1-1)}$$

Comment: The OP stated "We cannot use partial fractions ..."

Answer (score 1):

Use power (Laurent) series for the pole at zero:

$$\frac{\cos z}{z^2(z-1)}=-\frac1{1-z}\frac1{z^2}\left(1-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}{24}-\ldots\right)=$$

$$-\frac1{z^2}(1+z+z^2+\ldots)\left(1-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}{24}-\ldots\right)=$$

$$=-\frac1{z^2}\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}2\ldots\right)=\ldots-\frac1z+\ldots\implies Res(f)_{z=0}=-1$$

For the residue at $\;z=1\;$ much easier than using Laurent series is to use limits:

$$Res(f)_{z=1}=\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)f(z)=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{\cos z}{z^2}=\cos 1\implies$$

finally

$$\oint_{|z|=\frac32}\frac{\cos z}{z^2(z-1)}dz=2\pi i(-1+\cos 1)$$

Comment: Without usisng residues theorem

Comment: The above was done before the OP added that condition to his question...

Comment: I did not add anything. it is the OP addendum

Comment: @GuyFsone Indeed so.

Comment: you can rollback the post to see what I added.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that the poles $z=0$ (of order $2$) and $z=1$ (a simple pole) are inside circle $|z|=\dfrac32$ and since $\cos z$ is analytic, you can use residue theorem. Also with Cauchy integral formula and drawing a suit contour around $z=0$ and $z=1$ (for example $C_1$ and $C_2$) you may write
$$\int_{|z|=\frac32}\dfrac{\cos z}{z^2(z-1)}dz=\int_{C_1}\dfrac{\frac{\cos z}{z^2}}{(z-1)}dz+\int_{C_2}\dfrac{\frac{\cos z}{z-1}}{z^2}dz$$

Comment: Sorry, I wanted a solution without using the residue theorem. I edited my post

Comment: @abc This is **exactly** the same way the answer you accepted did...